# How can I configure TortoiseSVN to not show .class, .log and folder list when creating an svn patch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, patch

I am creating an SVN patch using TortoiseSVN. It gives me a list of modified files to choose from to create a patch. In my case I get a long list of `.class` files and a folder list, as well as`.log` files.

Is it possible to configure SVN to not show the list of `.class` files and folder list while creating an SVN patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a patch file from the **Check for modifications...** screen.

Since you've mentioned that `*.class` and `*.log` are already in your `svn:ignore` list, you should tell TortoiseSVN to not display them:

[image: Don't show ignored files, TortoiseSVN]

You could also sort the modified files list by extension, and not select the files with those extensions.

From the **Create Patch** screen, you could also deselect **Show unversioned files**:

[image: Don't show unversioned files, TortoiseSVN]

This assumes that the files were unversioned in the first place, because marking them ignored after already versioning them is pointless.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows you can do the following: Just rightclick any `*.class` or `*.log` file in the repofolder, go to the tab TortiseSVN-> Add to Ignorelist-> *.log/*.class.
If you sue the commandline tool. You had to configure a svn:ign propperty.

Comment: *.class *.log is already added in svn:ignore. This does not impacts the tortoisesvn create patch list.